# I am receiving an error message: Error: Failed to start application: Failed to start the session

Tags: fatal-error

When pulling up my website, southark.edu, I am presented with the following error message:

> Error: Failed to start application: Failed to start the session

I've not done anything to it since two days ago when it was working.

I had been hacked a couple of times recently and have been working with a developer to identify and kill the vulnerabilities.

Edit:  I tried to log into phpmyadmin and it would not let me, which leads me to think this could be a problem in the database.

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED:  The disk was full which stopped the site from coming up.
We emptied the trash bin of 200GB of data and the site came back up.